# Extra double quotes on export from SSMS to CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssms, export-to-csv, ssms-2017

Upon using a text editor to review exported results from SSMS to CSV I'm witnessing extra double quotes around the result values - not field names. I've used the concat function in my script to manually add a single pair of double quotes around each value and field name. So where I would expect "012345678" I'm actually seeing """012345678""".

It may be that my code is a bit too rudimentary

ex.:

```
SELECT CONCAT('"',ISNULL('012345678',''),'"') AS '"employee_id"'
FROM employees
```

More fields are selected I just included one as an example.

Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't quote the values in your SQL, let the export process do that. Effectively you're saying the value you want to export is `"012345678"` (***with*** the double quotes), however, as your CSV is quote identified, the double quotes in the string need to be escaped (to `""`), resulting in `"""012345678"""`. The first and last double quotes (`"`) are the quote identifiers, and then the others are the escaped double quotes from your value.

Comment: Don't do that single quote + double quote thing in the column alias either. You don't even need to quote that identifier anyway.

Comment: Larnu, I'm needing double quotes to appear when reviewing the export in a text editor or Excel. When I remove the quotes from script, I don't visibly see the needed double quotes in the export.

Comment: When you say "in the export" do you mean, for example, in Excel? If so, then no, you won't. If you open the file in a text editor, like notepad, you will.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't manually add in the **"** around your data fields. If you want a character around the fields use the `Text qualifier` option. In SSMS when using Task > Export to open the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, set the *Text qualifier* as shown below and  whatever character you set for the *Text qualifier* will be automatically put around each field.

[image]

You can find some documentation about text qualfiier here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-flat-file-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15#options-to-specify-general-page